# How to read exception details in MYSQL Diagnostic area

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql 5.7.14. The get diagnostics statement showing error though i am using 5.7. Sample lines what i am using are something like below where i need to extract error information but unfortunately it couldn't. please help me.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

BEGIN

 ROLLBACK;#I HAVE TO ROOL BACK A TRASACTION WHEN EVER AN EXCEPTION OCCURS.

 GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 ERRORSTATE=RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
 ERRORNUMBER=MYSQL_ERRNO, ERRORTEXT=MESSAGE_TEXT;

END;
```